# Can all Pokémon swim?

Tags: underwater, pokemon-tabletop-united

According to the core rules:

> Underwater Terrain is any water that a Pokémon or Trainer can be submerged in. You may not move through Underwater Terrain during battle if you do not have a Swim Capability.

Every Pokémon I could think to check has a Swim Capability, even Pokémon that I don't think should be able to be submerged (e.g. Charmander, Swim 3; Chandelure, Swim 4). Is this rule an oversight or are there Pokémon without a Swim speed listed?

Answer (score 2):

I found 22 Pokémon without a swim speed (and I think this is an exhaustive list):

- Weedle (Kakuna and Beedrill have Swim 2)
- Fletchling / Fletchinder / Talonflame
- Flaaffy / Ampharos (Mareep has Swim 2)
- Diglett / Dugtrio / Alolan Diglett / Alolan Dugtrio
- Elgyem (Beheeyem has Swim 3)
- Riolu (Lucario has Swim 2)
- Shuppet / Banette
- Eevee (Evolutions have Swim 3-8)
- Crandios / Rampardos
- Regirock / Regice / Registeel
- Terrakion (Other Swords of Justice have Swim 5-7)
- Hoopa Confined (Hoopa Unbound has Swim 5)

All these Pokémon have no Swim speed listed and therefore have no way to get one. This is because anything that says to increase a movement speed (such as Advanced Mobility) seems to only work when the Pokémon already has a number for that type of movement. Otherwise, any Pokémon could learn to teleport for 1 TP.

The only exception is Eevee, which can get Swim 3 by learning Dive from Vaporeon's TM/HM list via Underdog's Lessons (and from there can take Advanced Mobility for a total of 5). In fact, Dive is the only move that affects a Pokémon's Swim speed.

Is there a balance issue to letting any of these Pokémon swim? I doubt it. The list seems pretty arbitrary. Out of combat I would gloss over this. In combat, I would allow any Pokémon with a Levitate or Teleporter speed to use that in the water, and otherwise allow a Swim 1, the same as Pokémon like Aron. (However, in no way can you make a swimming Diglett or Dugtrio make sense conceptually.)